# return the item click order/position inside its container div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to return, console.log(); the clicked item and its position.
all containers have the same class name as you can see in this example:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

this is the javascript to return the clicked item :

```
$(".container .item").click(function(){
var position = "? not sure what to do here";
console.log(this + " position: "+position);
});
</script>
```

so the idea is if you click on the third div inside the second container it should return : container:2 item:3
this again without changing the DOM (trying to track site clicks without changing its original code.)
thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(this).index() will return the current position.
$(this).parent().index() will return the container div index.

```
$(".container .item").click(function(elm){

var containerIndex= $(this).parent().index();
var itemIndex = $(this).index();
console.log( 'container:' +containerIndex + ' ' + 'item:' +itemIndex);
});
```

[you can see it here](http://jsfiddle.net/5wf1hrko/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery function **[.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** that will return the position integer number of element.

> **Description:** Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

```
var position = $(this).index();
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$(".container .item").click(function(){
    var position = $(this).index();
    console.log(this + " position: "+position);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="item">0</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="item">0</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>

<div class="container"> 
    <div class="item">0</div>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `index()` method to get the position of the current element within it's container. From the `item()` you can then use `closest()` to get the relevant `.container`. Try this:

```
$(".container .item").click(function () {
    var containerIndex = $(this).closest('.container').index();
    var itemIndex = $(this).index();
    console.log('container: ' + containerIndex, 'item: ' + itemIndex);
});
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/51sz1c01/)